# How can I make a really fancy SELECT/option drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, templates

This must work on the iPhone and mobile browsers. This has to be lightweight.
I'm looking for a good CSS3 option.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a jQuery plugin, I've used it multiple times and I'm really glad with the results.  [select jQuery plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/). I do not have knowledge of being a css only option for this